# Route matching like Wordpress in Angular

Tags: wordpress, angular, angular2-routing

I'm working on an Angular theme for Wordpress and I'm having trouble setting up a routing scheme that mimics Wordpress.

In the routing module, I've got basic routing set up:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostListComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts/:slug',
    component: PostSingleComponent
  }
];
```

However, in Wordpress when displaying categories, the url is:

```
/posts/category/some-category/possible-sub-category
```

I guess the real question is can Angular routing match that path without considering the /category/ as a route parameter (:slug in this case)?

Comment: i think you could change your wordpress route or use hash `HashLocationStrategy` in Angular app

Comment: the goal is to match or mimic Wordpress's routing hierarchy, so adding hashes would not work

Comment: This may coming in a future version of Angular: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this, albeit in a limited way, is to take advantage of the order of path matching.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'posts',
    component: PostsComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts/category'
    component: CategoryComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts/category/:child-category'
    component: ChildCategoryComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts/category/:child-category/:sub-category'
    component: SubCategoryComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'posts/:post-id'
    component: PostComponent
  }
]
```

Since the posts/category path comes first, if that's in the URL it will render those components first. If the Router doesn't see the category string there, it will assume it is posts/:post-id and render the appropriate component.